# How to specify navtitle for table of contents in web output but NOT in pdf output?

Tags: xml, xml-documentation, dita

Given that the table-of-contents area for web output is rather narrow I would like to assume smaller navigation titles for web, but continue to present long topic titles in PDF output.

The following markup does not seem to work at all (with or without the `audience` attribute):

```
<task id="guid-76a10a16-9952-44fa-ad32-9b9cf2c3eee6">
    <title>Primary Topic Title</title>
    <titlealts audience="web">
        <navtitle>Short Title</navtitle>
    </titlealts>
</task>
```

Adding `locktitle="yes"` in the map also did not seem to make any difference:

```
<topicref type="task" href="primary-topic-title.dita" locktitle="yes"/>
```

The following works for web, but unfortunately also presents short titles in the PDF table-of-contents:

```
<topicref type="task" href="primary-topic-title.dita" locktitle="yes">
    <topicmeta>
        <navtitle>Short Title</navtitle>
    </topicmeta>
</topicref>
```

I tried using the following to target Web and PDF separately, but this caused errors to occur during the transform process stating that I was attempting to reference topics outside of the processing context. This works fine for web, but when examining the PDF output there are links to the ".dita" files using the "file:/" protocol instead of cross-references within the PDF file.

```
<topicref audience="pdf" type="task" href="primary-topic-title.dita"/>

<topicref audience="web" type="task" href="primary-topic-title.dita" locktitle="yes">
    <topicmeta>
        <navtitle>Short Title</navtitle>
    </topicmeta>
</topicref>
```

Note: I am using the [Ditac](http://www.xmlmind.com/ditac) processor by XML Mind

Answer (score 2):

Although I'm not familiar with the DITAC tool specifically, I will describe the approach that will work in the DITA Open Toolkit and and other tools offering full support for the DITA spec.

Your original approach is the right one:

```
<task id="guid-76a10a16-9952-44fa-ad32-9b9cf2c3eee6">
    <title>Primary Topic Title</title>
    <titlealts audience="web">
        <navtitle>Short Title</navtitle>
    </titlealts>
</task>
```

Your processing must use a different ditaval file for PDF and web output. The PDF ditaval file must include:

```
<prop action="exclude" att="audience" val="web" />
```

The web ditaval file must include:

```
<prop action="include" att="audience" val="web" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately DITA has only the `print` attribute to filter based on the output type and it cannot directly be used on `navtitle` element. You could use

```
<topicref print="printonly" href="primary-topic-title.dita"/>
<topicref print="no" href="primary-topic-title.dita" locktitle="yes">
  <topicmeta>
    <navtitle>Short Title</navtitle>
  </topicmeta>
</topicref>
```

But that would be duplicating the topic references. It may be easier to add a custom profiling attribute based on `props` and filter based on that. That way you can only condition the `navtitle`.

Comment: Thanks, this approach certainly seems to work! Why does this work but using `audience` and ditaval filtering not? I am not sure what you mean by your second suggestion. Do you mean something like `<navtitle props="web">Short Title</navtitle>`?

Comment: Ahh, it doesn't work, it's just the other way around. This time smaller navigation titles are shown in web, longer titles in PDF, links are correct in PDF but links are incorrect in web `file:/C:/Path/to/Topic.dita`.